NextJS tailwind CSS problem --- The `shadow-[inset_10px_-50px_94px_0_rgb(199,` class does not exist
My next.js app is throwing this css error
Syntax error: C:....styles\globals.css The shadow-[inset_10px_-50px_94px_0_rgb(199, class does not exist. If shadow-[inset_10px_-50px_94px_0_rgb(199, is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a @layer directive. (111:5)
109 |
110 | .copy_btn {

111 |     @apply w-7 h-7 rounded-full bg-white/10 shadow-[inset_10px_-50px_94px_0_rgb(199, 199, 199, 0.2)] backdrop-blur flex justify-center items-center cursor-pointer;
|     ^
112 | }
113 |
-- inner error --
Syntax error: C:....styles\globals.css The shadow-[inset_10px_-50px_94px_0_rgb(199, class does not exist. If shadow-[inset_10px_-50px_94px_0_rgb(199, is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a @layer directive. (111:5)

109 |
110 | .copy_btn {

111 |     @apply w-7 h-7 rounded-full bg-white/10 shadow-[inset_10px_-50px_94px_0_rgb(199, 199, 199, 0.2)] backdrop-blur flex justify-center items-center cursor-pointer;
|     ^
112 | }
113 |

image
i want this to get solved

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It seems that Tailwind is not able to process the provided class.
This is mainly because you are adding whitespaces while setting rgb() value.
It will confuse tailwind and consider shadow-[inset_10px_-50px_94px_0_rgb(199, , 199, and 0.2)] as separate classes.
To avoid this underscore can be used. Follow this docs
Or in this case simply remove the whitespaces.
shadow-[inset_10px_-50px_94px_0_rgb(199,199,199,0.2)]
